# In JAX-RS, entire JSON string is being posted

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs, soapui

I have a simple Jersey POST method that accepts JSON. I am using SOAP UI to test, using POST and media type application/JSON. 
Within the request body I have JSON:

```
{
    email:"test"
}
```

When I test this, the string I expect to come into the service as test actually comes in as the entire JSON string. Not sure what's wrong here, it should work according to the docs.

```
@POST
@Path("/TEST")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response testJaxRs(String email){
    //  email = "{
    //      email:"test"
    //  }"
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to deserialize it to a bean, then you can accept the post body as a map of key-value pairs. For example:

```
public Response testJaxRs(Map<String, String> body) {
    body.get("email") // "test"
    ...
```

Comment: Is it JAX RS standard or  a Jersey feature?

Comment: @pedrofb I am not sure if it is an official standard. Personally, I have only used it with JAX-RS 1.1 on WebSphere Liberty Profile (which I believe uses the Apache Wink implementation).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Jersey **1.x**, then to receive your *Json* as an object you need to declare the *POJO* and annotate it with `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement`:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class EmailTest{

    String email;

    public String getEmail(){
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Then you have to use this class in your controller:

```
@POST
@Path("/TEST")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response testJaxRs(Email email){
    System.out.println(email.getEmail()); // prints "test"
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Finally you've to add `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` as `<init-param>` of your servlet adding the package or packages (separated by `,`) pointing to your controller packages. For example in your `web.xml`:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>org.app.controllers</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a bean

```
 public class Email{
      private String email;

     //getters&setters
   }
```

---

```
  public Response testJaxRs(Email emailBean){
```

Note that you need to add the dependencies to decode json. e.g Jackson and add this mapping to jersey servlet in `web.xml`>  See full example here: https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

```
<web-app ...>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.yourpackage</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```